# Map an array created from a variable to render said number of elements in Grommet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, dynamic-arrays, grommet

I have a textbox where user inputs a number which is stored in a state `value`.
Now I want to create an array `[0, 1, 2, ..., value]`.
This array will be used to create `(value + 1)` number of boxes/divs each with their corresponding ids.

Now I've tried this

```
{(value) && 
  ([...Array(value).keys()].map(id => (
    <NodeBox id={id} >
      <h3>{id}</h3>
    </NodeBox>
  )))
}
```

But it created only one box with h3 text '0' in it. I have the state, the NodeBox, everything defined properly. There seems to be no problem with it.

---

If I do this

```
{(value) && 
  ([0, 1, 2, 3].map(id => (
    <NodeBox id={id} >
       <h3>{id}</h3>
    </NodeBox>
  )))
}
```

I get results as expected. I get 4 boxes containing the corresponding number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that value is a string instead of a number.
When you use `new Array()` or Array.from(), you look at the length of something instead of the actual value. So I think that `value` is a string representing a number below 10, which would give it a length of 1, matching your output.

So I would use `Array.from({ length: value }).map(( id, index ) => (<NodeBox id={index} >)` so that it does not matter if value is a string or a number.

The alternative would be to parse the string into a number before using it in `Array(value)`.